# is each request/thread configured in a jmeter test using a different port when connecting to a web server?

Tags: multithreading, http, jmeter, httprequest, performance-testing

A friend of mine got the following error when using a high amount of threads (10k threads):

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect at 
java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) at 
java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) at 
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at 
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) at 
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at 
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at
```

For what I found out, it looks like each thread in jmeter uses a different port. Therefore, he needs to add a bigger port range in the client machine. But I got curious of why each threads needs to use a different port. Cant they use the same port for doing the http web request? I can probably write a c# console app that sends 10k requests with the web request object and wont have a port conflict issue because each thread uses the same port. Is it possible to have Jmeter to use one single port? What exactly am I missing to understand here?

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell you this is the standard behaviour.
The same applies for browsers. 
Yes in your case you have to tune the Jmeter client OS to use more port.

I think the server can use the port+IP map to return the right data to the right client.